# image on top of background color for html list using css

Tags: html, css

I'd want to impose an image (that has transparency) on top a color background for an html list using css.

Currently I do:

```css
ul li.myclass {
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: url('/w3images/myimage.png') no-repeat left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="myclass"> example </li>
</ul>
```

but this only shows the color not the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
ul li.myclass {
    background: #ddd url('/w3images/myimage.png') left no-repeat;
}
```

If the image is transparent and/or doesn't cover the whole area, then the color comes into play. Example:

```css
body {
   background:#ddd url('https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/139694/isolated/lists/ef87f11007e9a062a4cf7f004fbe5443-bird-silhouette-4.png') left top no-repeat;
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Comment: nice, works perfect.  Also the image goes all the way to the left.  Is there a way to add 1 or two space, then image and then the ul text? i mean instead of left being completely to the left put a paddding...

Comment: yes, it is background position or in shortcut background property try to set some value for it like: background:#ddd url('img.png') 25% top no-repeat; Instead of 25% you could use a value in px etc. according to your needs.